# oifits module for python3

Tags: python-3.6, fits

when I open a *.fits file in OIFitsExplorer, I obtain a structure as in the figure.

[image]

How can I get data only from GRAVITY_SC_P1 in oifits python3 module?

I access the data as follows:

```
target = "Zeta_Ori"

for infile in sys.argv[1:]:

    obj = oifits.open(infile)
    obj.info()

    outfile = os.path.basename(infile).replace("fits", "dat")
    fout = open("dat_vis/" + outfile, "w")

    for vis2 in obj.vis2:       

        if vis2.target.target == target:
            fout.write("# %s\n" % (vis2))
            fout.write("# %s\n" % (vis2.target))

            t1 = astropy.time.Time(vis2.timeobs, scale='utc', format='datetime')
            t2 = t1.tdb

            for i in range(len(vis2.wavelength.eff_wave)):
                if vis2.vis2data[i] != "--":
                    fout.write("%22.8f    %32.16e %32.16e    %32.16e %32.16e    %32.16e %32.16e %8s\n" % (t2.jd, vis2.ucoord, vis2.vcoord, vis2.wavelength.eff_wave[i], vis2.wavelength.eff_band[i], vis2.vis2data[i], vis2.vis2err[i], str(vis2.station[0])[:2]+str(vis2.station[1])[:2]))


    fout.close()
```

However, the data are from all four "subdirectories" (INSNAME), not only from a chosen one. How to select data with a given INSNAME? Thank you

Comment: I don't know Python enough but I am sure it's an easy restriction to implement. Either your sys.argv[1:] is too wide and you can limit it just through the input command line, or you can compare the "infile" variable before going deeper into it (can you display it to know how much file are looped into?). Anyway, I think you will not meet a lot of OIFITS experts here. You could maybe e-mail the author of OIFITS.PY directly : https://github.com/pboley/oifits

Comment: Or try to replace the first line target = "Zeta_Ori" with target="GRAVITY_SC_P1"

Comment: sys.argv[1:] is just for several *.fits file.  target="GRAVITY_SC_P1" does not work. Thank you, I will contact the author.